# Start an Activity After Sms Received

Tags: android, android-studio, sms, android-broadcastreceiver

So I'm trying to find a way on how to start a new activity after the conditions. Tried calling a function but it won't work. I hope someone can help. I'm just a beginner please respect.

```
if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                messageReceived += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                messageReceived += "\n";

            }

            senderPhoneNumber = msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress();


        }

        if ((messageReceived == "xxxxxx") && (senderPhoneNumber == "xxxxxxxxx")) {

           //If these conditions are true I want to start a new Activity
        }
```

Comment: Use `.equals()` to compare the content of strings.

Comment: thanks but my problem is not with the conditions but on how to execute an activity if both conditions are true.

Comment: If you use `==` instead of `.equals()`, your condition will always evaluate to `false`.

Comment: thanks for the help. But still not my main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can start `Activity` by using **context** parameter of `onRecieve()` method

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //start activity
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.example", "com.example.ActivityName");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```